# Problemas con las rutas en Laravel Error 404

Tags: php, laravel, rutas, error404, routes

Estoy teniendo problemas al cargar las rutas, la home funciona perfectamente y de manera local tambien, pero al publicar mi proyecto con Ferozo las rutas me dirigen a Error 404. Acá dejo el  el archivo de rutas

````
Route::resource('/contacto', 'ContactoController');
Route::resource('/colecciones', 'ColeccionUserController');
Route::resource('/categorias', 'CategoriaUserController');
Route::resource('/trabaja', 'TrabajaController');
Route::resource('/admin-gonmec-41/colecciones', 'ColeccionController');
Route::resource('/admin-gonmec-41/categorias', 'CategoriaController');
Route::resource('/admin-gonmec-41', 'AdminController'); ```
````

Comment: ¿Estas en un servidor apache?

Comment: Ya está publicado en el hosting, en el servidor local funciona perfecto

Comment: Entonces configura el servidor del hosting igual que tu servidor local y debería funcionar.